# Using .htaccess to block directory breaks css and images

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

Apologies if this has been asked already. I tried to do an extensive search but I don't know much about htaccess so I don't know which questions have been relevant.

Right now I'm setting up a pretty expansive system with php that requires several pages and functions. To keep things simple and manageable, I have one single file "economy.php" that then requires files from the "/economy/" directory.

I read on another question that the best way to deal with the files within only being accessed from the economy.php file is to use an htaccess file in /economy with `deny from all`. This worked, except now the images and stylesheet within the /economy directory don't work.

The solution I can think of is to create a directory /economy/pages/ and throw the php files and htaccess file in there. But that's sloppy, and I'm assuming there's an easier way to handle it.

What's my best course of action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look at the [Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files) apache directive
  So you should have something like that :

```
<Files ~ "\.(php|.htaccess|php5)$">
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Hope this helps ...

Mimiz

Answer (score 0):

The "deny from all" is blocking the user's browser from accessing the CSS and image files. Best bet is to break up the directory structure. Create top level directories for images, css, js, source, etc. Then update the paths in the code accordingly. You can then use an Apache config (or .htaccess which is slower) to deny outside access to the source dir.

Comment: So there's no better way than adding the /economy/pages/ directory?